# Restarting Apache Felix

Tags: java-8, apache-felix

I am doing a self updating application using `Apache Felix` and I can't seem to forcibly restart `Felix` after update. I did some tricks to simulate the restart process by using some kind of application `State`.

```
public class LauncherActivator implements BundleActivator {

    public static LauncherState State;

    @Override
    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        ...
        LauncherApplication.State = LauncherState.READY;

        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            try {
                new LauncherApplication().start();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(LauncherActivator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        });

    }    
}
```

If there are updates detected I would just change the global state to `LauncherAppliation.State = LauncherState.RESTART;` if the application detects the change in `State` I will just simply call `BUNDLE_MAP.get('application.activator').update();`, `BUNDLE_MAP` is some kind of a `HashMap` that stores all running bundles on start.

I tested it and it worked, I can see in the logs that the activator bundle is being updated and the simple restart mechanism reruns the activator bundle but there are times that it doesn't rerun the activator bundle and the bundle state is already `ACTIVE`.

So what would be the right way to restart Apache Felix using the activator bundle or any bundle in general?

Answer (score 0):

It is all in the documentation all this time!

[**Starting the Framework Instance**](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-framework/apache-felix-framework-launching-and-embedding.html#starting-the-framework-instance)

> The `start()` method is used to start the framework instance. If the `init()` method was not invoked prior to calling `start()`, then it is invoked by `start()`. The two methods result in two different framework state transitions:
>
> - `init()` results in the framework instance in the `Bundle.STARTING` state.
> - `start()` results in the framework instance in the `Bundle.ACTIVE` state.
>
> The `init()` method is necessary since the framework does not have a `BundleContext` when it is first created, so a transition to the `Bundle.STARTING` state is required to acquire its context (via `Bundle.getBundleContext()`) for performing various tasks, such as installing bundles. Note that the Felix framework also provides the `felix.systembundle.activators` property that serves a similar purpose, but is not standard. After the `init()` method completes, the follow actions have been performed:
>
> - Event handling is enabled.
> - The security manager is installed if it is enabled.
> - The framework is set to start level 0.
> - All bundles in the bundle caches are reified and their state is set to `Bundle.INSTALLED`.
> - The framework gets a valid `BundleContext`.
> - All framework-provided services are made available (e.g., `PackageAdmin`, `StartLevel`, etc.).
> - The framework enters the `Bundle.STARTING` state.
>
> A call to `start()` is necessary to start the framework instance, if the `init()` method is invoked manually. Invoking `init()` or `start()` on an already started framework as no effect.

[**Stopping the Framework Instance**](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-framework/apache-felix-framework-launching-and-embedding.html#stopping-the-framework-instance)

> To **stop** the framework instance, invoke the `stop()` method, which will *asynchronously stop the framework*. To know when the framework has finished its shutdown sequence, use the `waitForStop()` method to **wait** until it is complete. A stopped framework will be in the `Bundle.RESOLVED` state. It is possible to **restart** the framework, using the normal combination of `init()/start()` methods as previously described.

[**Launching a Framework**](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-framework/apache-felix-framework-launching-and-embedding.html#launching-a-framework)

> **Launching** a framework is fairly simple and involves only four steps:
>
> 1. Define some configuration properties.
> 2. Obtain framework factory.
> 3. Use factory to create framework with the configuration properties.
> 4. Invoke the `Framework.start()` method.
>
> In reality, the first step is optional, since all properties will have reasonable defaults, but if you are creating a launcher you will generally want to more than that, such as automatically installing and starting bundles when you **start** the framework instance. The default Felix launcher defines reusable functionality to automatically install and/or start bundles upon framework startup.